# Invisible to the eye - What is it that I am speaking of

Tags: riddle

> It is invisible to the eye,
>   yet it is a stranger to no one.
>   It weighs less than air,
>   yet it is sharper and more keen than any knife, sword, or blade.
>   It comes from nothing,
>   but it has the power to vanquish armies.

What is it that I am speaking of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer that I remember was:

> **hunger**

but it could also be

> time or cold.

Comment: Now that is funny!!! ;-)

Comment: Note to mods: It would be better not to delete this answer for lack of an explanation. An explanation can be found in rev 2 of this answer...

Comment: I don't feel this answer needs an explanation.  Once you know the answer and confront it to the text, you should understand every line.  That's how a good riddle works.

Comment: It is a classic riddle I heard before and the answer was hunger.  But then I thought of other equally valid answers, which I added.  None is perfect though.  Hunger and cold can in fact be seen.  Time would be invisible but "sharp as a knife" doesn't apply so well.

Answer (score 7):

You are speaking of

> Time‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

It is invisible to the eye

> You cannot see time

yet it is a stranger to no one

> But everyone is familiar with it

It weighs less than air

> It has no weight

yet it is sharper and more keen than any knife, sword, or blade.

> Time cannot be blocked, it pierces any armour.

It comes from nothing

> Time has no 'source' of which we know

but it has the power to vanquish armies.

> The passage of time can destroy anything, including armies

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> Intellect

It is invisible to the eye,

> Intellect is abstract so it can't be seen.

yet it is a stranger to no one.

> Everyone has intellect (ranging from a little bit to a lot).

It weighs less than air,

> Intellect is abstract so it has no weight.

yet it is sharper and more keen than any knife, sword, or blade.

> Some people are said to possess a sharp or keen intellect.

It comes from nothing,

> Intellect comes from the mind, which due to its abstractness could be considered nothing.

but it has the power to vanquish armies.

> One must typically use intellect to win a war.

Comment: I thought the same thing! :D

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> Thought

It is invisible to the eye

> You cannot see thought.

yet it is a stranger to no one

> Even a strange thought is not a stranger

it weighs less than air

> of course

it is sharper than a keen knife, word or blade

> thought can pierce the vastness of space, or the microcosm of an atom which a blade cannot do

it comes from nothing

> who can truly say where a thought comes from?  some theories speculate that even thoughts we consider our own, might originate from the unknown (nothing)

but it has the power to vanquish armies

> indeed, without thought, one cannot vanquish an army.